# Custom post_per_page not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm having troubles  displaying lists of custom_post_type on my website.
I can get the posts but what is not working is "post_per_page". It gets ignored and I get every post of that type.

Here is the code I have on my home page (it's not working elsewhere too):

```
<?php 
// 1ST

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_1',
    'post_per_page' => 1,
);

$custom_post_1 = new WP_Query($args);

if ($custom_post_1->have_posts()) : while ($custom_post_1->have_posts()) : $custom_post_1->the_post(); ?>

    // My content

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php 
// 2ND

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_2',
    'post_per_page' => 3,
);

$custom_post_2 = new WP_Query($args);

if ($custom_post_2->have_posts()) : while ($custom_post_2->have_posts()) : $custom_post_2->the_post(); ?>

    // My content

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php
// 3RD

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_3',
    'post_per_page' => 1,
);

$custom_post_3 = new WP_Query($args);

if ($custom_post_3->have_posts()) : while ($custom_post_3->have_posts()) : $custom_post_3->the_post(); ?>

    // My content

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`posts_per_page` and not `post_per_page`  my friend

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the `pagination` parameter of WP_Query, as per that it will be `posts_per_page` instead <s>post_per_page</s>.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

So as per that your query will be as follows,

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_1',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$custom_post_1 = new WP_Query($args);
```

Hope this one helps :)

Comment: Thank you too mate!

Comment: I did but my rep is too low to let your post score increase be displayed. It's recorded anyway ;)